# MaskFormatter a un TextField para número de telefono en Java Eclipse WindowsBuilder

Tags: java

Mí código del TextField:

```
JTextField txtNumeroDeOrigen = new JTextField();
txtNumeroDeOrigen.setBounds(237, 11, 125, 20);
contentPane.add(txtNumeroDeOrigen);
txtNumeroDeOrigen.setColumns(10);
```

En ese campo yo solicito un número de telefono: ###-###-####. El usuario ingresa, ejemplo: 7875556666

Me gustaría tener un MaskFormatter, para que escriba en el TextField, ejemplo: (787) 555-6666.

Así aprovecho y solo permito el ingreso de números, y no letras o signos raros.

He visto ejemplos pero, no me funcionan. Alguna solución simple?.

Saludos!.

Comment: debes aceptar una respuesta, o votar +1 a la respuesta que te ayude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de [`JTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html), puedes utilizar [`JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)* y, además, una instancia de [`javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html). Es decir (por ejemplo):

```
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("(###) ###-####");
        JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField);
    }

}
```

[image: sin datos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

<sup>* Para saber más, puedes echar un vistazo a [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) dentro de [*The Java Tutorials*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).</sup>

Comment: Hola, he tratado y tengo el mismo error que se me ha presentado con los ejemplos anteriores. Comento que tengo instanciados estos: import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;, import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;. Luego, aquí el error: http://oi63.tinypic.com/2l8hg8i.jpg, espero puedas ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: @RobertGomez Agregar `throws ParseException` no olvidar.

Comment: Tengo mi clase llamada GUI, es correcto hacer otro main con el throws ParseException dentro de mi main GUI?. Tengo: public class GUI extends JFrame {, y luego de esto tengo mi GUI, o sea, el frame: public GUI() {.

Comment: [Aquí](http://pastie.org/private/4b4wajh1qzh3d7scfqhg) encontrarás otra variante de lo mismo. Adicionalmente, te animo a conocer más y dominar el lenguaje.

Comment: Hecho, he logrado hacerlo gracias, aun estoy aprendiendo WindowsBuilder, poco a poco. Tengo una ultima pregunta, tengo un boton llamado limpiar el cual deja en blanco todos los campos, incluyendo el "(___) ___-____" del campo del número telefonco. Las rayas desaparecen, como puedo hacer que aparezcan las rayas nuevamente?, sin los numeros?. Gracias por ayudarme, se te agradece mucho.

Answer (score 2):

La Opción planteada por @Paul es buena. Usar [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) para tener dicha mascara, pero para un`TextField` se podría crear una clase que extienda de [PlainDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html), evaluando mediante el método [insertString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html#insertString(int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet)) de acuerdo al formato que se le desea dar. `(para el ejemplo (###)###-###. sería)`

```
public class Mascara extends PlainDocument {

  public void insertString(int arg0, String arg1, AttributeSet arg2) 
    throws BadLocationException
   {
       /* Verificamos si la entrada es un número */
       if(Character.isDigit(arg1.charAt(0)))
       {

          switch(arg0)
          {
              /* si está vacía insertamos el (  */
              case 0: 
                   super.insertString(arg0,"("+ arg1, arg2);
                   break;
              case 4: 
                   super.insertString(arg0, ") "+arg1, arg2);
                   break;
              case 9:
                   super.insertString(arg0, "-"+arg1, arg2);
                   break;
              case 14:/* si es 13 entonces no permitimos que sea ingresado el valor*/
                   return;
              default:
                  super.insertString(arg0, arg1, arg2);
          }

       }

   }
}
```

Asignaría el `Document` al `TextField` así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   JTextField txt = new JTextField();
   txt.setDocument(new Mascara());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txt);
}
```

Comment: Probé tu solución y funciona pero, sabes de alguna forma para agregarle al textfield: (___) ___-____, a medida que se valla escribiendo los números, se van llenando los _  ?

Comment: Se podría realizar, pero para dicha tarea existe `JFormattedTextField` , te simplifica las cosas. expuse está respuesta como una opción. :)

Comment: Tengo mi clase llamada GUI, es correcto hacer otro main con el throws ParseException dentro de mi main GUI?. Tengo: public class GUI extends JFrame {, y luego de esto tengo mi GUI, o sea, el frame: public GUI() {. Dónde pondría el throws ParseException?

Comment: es que yo no uso ningun main en mi programa. No importa?, o sea, yo uso Eclipse y estoy haciendo una interfaz con Windowsbuilder, esta no crea ningun main en el codigo, por eso te pregunto que donde pondría el throws ParseException ya que no cuento con main.

Comment: En los dos , en el main(donde haces la instancia de tu GUI) y en el constructor de tu GUI así `public GUI() throws ParseException{ ... }` ... es raro que no tengas un método **main**  , ya que sin está no podrías correr el programa.

Comment: En Eclipse, creas un JFrame para hacer tu interfaz, el programa no te crea ningun main en el codigo, siempre me ha funcionado así. He logrado hacer funcionar el MaskFormatter con JFormattedTextField pero, tengo un problema, espero te haya pasado y sepas solucionarlo, porque yo no. Corro el programa, escribo el número, tengo un botón "Limpiar" que borra todos los campos, al hacerlo y hacer clic en otro campo diferente, el número que había escrito anteriormente, reaparece. Te ha pasado?.

Comment: No, esto formaría parte de otra pregunta. esto se hará muy extenso... ya que no es un chat. gracias. (si tienes otra duda o problema, realizar una nueva pregunta)

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar `String.replaceFirst()`

```
long phoneNum = 123456789L;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(phoneNum).replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1)-$2-$3"));
```